# trying to understanding why python is splitting a str in single characters when using join

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6.4 and i am trying to figure out why python is splitting my str variable into individual characters. here is what i am doing

```
test1 = 'hello'
test2 = 'world'
test3 = '\n\n'.join(f'{test1} {test2}')
print(test3)
```

returns:

```
h

e

l

l

o

w

o

r

l

d
```

Can some explain why is python splitting each of my string per character?

Then how do i get it to just return?

```
hello world
```

Comment: because `join` treats its arguments as iterables. iterating over strings produces the individual letters which in your case are *joined* using two new line characters (`/n/n`)

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: If you just want "hello world" why are you joining at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because probably in OP's mind `test1 + test2` is *joining* when it actually is (in Python terminology) *concatenating*

Comment: @Ev.Kounis but they're already joining/concatenating them in the f-string

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think it is safe to say that they are *confused* xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"something".join(some_iterable)
```

will take each element from `some_iterable` and put  in between. In your case

```
"\n\n".join("hello world")
```

takes each element from the string "hello world" (i.e. each character) and puts \n\n in between. So you get each character and then two newlines after it.

You don't need the `join` in your case. just do

```
test3=f'{test1} {test2}\n\n'
```